# Localization in Spartacus template

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am new to spartacus and am trying to implement language locatiolization in my application. I understand we can use 'cxTranslate' as a pipe in template interpolation for data which is received from the component. But is there a way or best practise where I can use similar structure for hard coded text in the HTML.

Comment: cxTranslate is not for data from the component.  Typically the components will have localised fields on the server-side & you should see localised content returned in the API response

Answer (score 0):

You can specify translation key directly in templates like in example below:

```
<h2>{{'contactUs.recentProducts' | cxTranslate}}</h2>
```

If you use json chunks for translations, you can use following configuration:

```
    providers: [provideConfig({

    i18n: {

      backend: {

        loadPath: 'assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'

      },

      resources: {

        en: translations

      },

      chunks: {

        ...translationChunksConfig,

        contactUs: ['contactUs'],

      },

    }

  })],
```

json file is located in:

```
 src/assets/i18n-assets/en/contactUs.json
```

and contains:

```
{

  "contactUs": {

    "recentProducts": "Recently purchased products"

  }

}
```

For more info please refer to Spartacus documentation https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/